# refresh the command inside sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

The date command inside `sed` isn't updating on each line.

I'm trying to learn `sed` and other basic commands for scripting. In this example I'm trying to append a timestamp next to the ping time (a solution provided by another user in a previous question), but the `date` command doesn't seem to update on each line. I've tried to read about `sed` options, but all my attempts so far have been fruitless

`ping 8.8.8.8 | sed --unbuffered  "s/.*time=\([0-9\.]*\).*/\1 $(date +%T)/"`

I'm expecting

```
85.2 10:59:26
140 10:59:27
231 10:59:28
97.7 10:59:29
117 10:59:30
80.9 10:59:31
```

But I'm getting

```
85.2 10:59:26
140 10:59:26
231 10:59:26
97.7 10:59:26
117 10:59:26
80.9 10:59:26
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `$(date)` is only evaluated once, before the shell runs `sed`. If you want it run each time, try the `e` option to the `sed` substitution. This is a GNU extension to `sed`.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8 | sed --unbuffered  's/.*time=\([0-9\.]*\).*/echo \1 $(date +%T)/e'
```

Or if you wanted to avoid the `echo` and the `$()`:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8 | sed --unbuffered  's/.*time=\([0-9\.]*\).*/date "+\1 %T"/e'
```

Comment: Ah amazing! Thank you i'll read more about it. Also thanks for the edit :)

Comment: The first one is more human-readable. How is /date "+\1 %T" parsed as regex and option under the same " " in the second one.

Comment: Also isn't the + supposed to be before the %? how come it is placed before the regex anchor? I'm more confused!

Comment: I agree the first one is more obvious. In the second one, the double quotes aren't special to the shell or to `sed` because they are in the single quotes surrounding the `sed` command. `sed` will happily substitute the `\1` and `date` will happily print any non-format strings literally.

Comment: Try `date '+Hello, World'` and see what happens :-)

Comment: Oh thank you! i've never tried to fiddle with the date command and never payed attention to the difference between double and single quotes in the shell environment  (except for echo command maybe) but it's very interesting. i'll try to read more about the topic.

Comment: No problems. Thanks for the interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

There is already a tool that does this.  See `ts` from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package. For example:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | cut -d= -f4 | ts %T
```

Output:

```
14:06:43 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
14:06:43 28.5 ms
14:06:44 41.2 ms
14:06:45 88.4 ms
14:06:46 26.6 ms
14:06:47 23.3 ms
```

Comment: Yeah i've read about ts, but i'm trying to learn the POSIX tools and making my scripts POSIX compliant, thus reducing the dependencies as much as i can. i'm very new to shell scripting so no fancy tools yet :D