# Command substitution inside sed is not working as expected

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write  a bash script to get the logs from a certain timeframe by reading the log file

I am trying to use the following sed command

```sh
sed -n '/2019-12-09 03:47:26/,/2019-12-09 03:48:26/p' mqerror.log.20191209
```

It works fine as above, and able to retrieve the logs during that timeframe,
 but when i try with command substitution inside sed, itseems not working. kindly help

```sh
sed -n '/`date +'%Y-%m-%d'` 03:47:26/,/`date +'%Y-%m-%d'` 03:48:26/p' mqerror.log.`date +'%Y%m%d'`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed substitution with bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Comment: also, use `$()` instead of backticks, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Does this answer your question? [refresh the command inside sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427767/refresh-the-command-inside-sed)

Answer (score 0):

After putting in double quotes as below. It is working as expected

sed -n "/`date +'%Y-%m-%d'` 0$PREV_HOUR:*:/,/`date +'%Y-%m-%d'` 0$CURR_HOUR:*:/p" mqerror.log.`date +'%Y%m%d'`